# Programmatically edit text in DataGridViewCell 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I need to edit the text of a DataGridViewCell. To be specific, I need to change the text from `-1` to `"N/A"`

First I tried this:

```
dgResults.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "N/A";
```

But it complained at runtime:

[image]

After that, I tried changing the datatype of the column:

```
dTable.Columns[0].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
```

and I get this error:

```
Cannot change DataType of a column once it has data.
```

I have no access to the database and cannot modify it.

Comment: How about: `dgResults.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = double.NaN`; ?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Not exactly what I need, but close. Is there no way I can the column to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by handling the [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event.

Comment: Awesome. Used `e.Value = "N/A";` in that event and it worked. Thank you, I've wasted too much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u changing datatype of datatable? Why not change column type of dgv? try this:

```
dgResults.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(string);
dgResults.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "N/A";
```

Use appropriate column index

Comment: how are you adding rows? datatable as datasource? In that case datatype of datatable and dgv should match for corresponding columns. Why cant u fetch the values from db as string instead of as double?

Comment: That still does not help me. Let's say I got the column as an INTEGER from the database, and it's in a DataTable. How can I convert that integer column to a string before I add it "manually" to the datagridview?

Comment: @David converting integer to string is no big deal if you are to manually add to dgv.